# Read argument with spaces from windows cmd Python

Tags: python, sys

I'm trying to read arguments with spaces in windows cmd.

So here is the code.

```
from avl_tree import *
import sys,os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    avl = AVLTreeMap()
    infile = sys.argv[1] + '.txt'
    avl._preprocessing(infile)
    avl._interface(infile)
```

I've written it as sys.argv[1] since I'm gonna type in the cmd as following:

```
python filename.py textfilename
```

But then if the text file has spaces in the name it won't work like that.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put textfile name in quotes

Comment: `python "filename.py" "argument2" "argument3" ...`

Comment: I see. That certainly works. But is there any way I could change the code to make it work?

Comment: This is a command prompt / terminal side problem so that is where you have to fix it from...

Comment: The command interpreter discards the spacing actually used on the command line before the Python interpreter is even started, so you *must* fix this in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hacky fix, and I wouldn't necessarily suggest it because it will mess with other arguments you might need to add later but you could do something like this:

```
infile = " ".join(sys.argv[1:]) + '.txt'
```

So you if you run the program like this:

```
python filename.py my file name
```

infile will equal `"my file name.txt"`

Comment: Okay, so this seems like it will take all the arguments as "infile" after .py. Am I right?

Comment: @zakels Correct. If you want to add additional arguments, make them `argv[1] ` and change my code to `argv[2:]`.

Comment: This won't work, though, if the file name contains consecutive spaces, or leading or trailing whitespace.